# Creating a radial menu using very limited css and js

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, menu

So I know that the question of how to make a radial menu has come up before and I am aware that some people have done absolutely amazing things already, but! I have to make one and I can't use anything more than css and js. The problem is, I have to implement the menu on the clients piece of crap drag and drop editor. It doesn't have anything fancy installed and isn't the most wonderful environment to work in.

To make matters worse, it has to be compatible back to IE8. I know. Trust me.

I was initially thinking of using a bunch of divs shaped as triangles layered over each other, but then I would have to cut off all of the tips poking out. Not sure how to do that.

Any ideas?

By the way, this is the triangle idea: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg9Su.jpg

Comment: I would use SVGs with raphael.js

Comment: try doing `border-radius: 50%;` on your menu :)

Comment: @Mohammad Wont that just add a circular border around the menu? That won't make pie shaped slices will it?